# BlToolkit Oracle Guid Insert in asp .net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, guid, bltoolkit

I tried to insert an entity to oracle database with BlToolkit. The connection is with System.Data.OracleClient. Everything is ok with ms sql server. But, when I migrate to oracle, insert for guid gives me error. Select works perfectly. Any advice?

***Model:***

```
[TableName("TEST")]
public class Test
{
    [MapField("TEST_ID")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid TestId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Kodu")]
    [MapField("TEST_KODU")]
    public string TestKodu { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Test Kısa Adı")]
    [MapField("TEST_KISA_ADI")]
    public string TestKisaAd { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Test Adı")]
    [MapField("TEST_ADI")]
    public string TestAdi { get; set; }
    public Test()
    {
    }
    public Test(Guid _id, string _kod, string _adi, string _kisaAdi)
    {
        TestId = _id;
        TestKodu = _kod;
        TestKisaAd = _kisaAdi;
        TestAdi = _adi;
    }
}
```

***DbManager:***

```
public class DbProvider : DbManager
    {
        public DbProvider() : base("ElabConnectionString")
        {

        }    
    }
```

***In Action:***

```
var db = new DbProvider();
db.Insert(test);
```

***Given Error:***

```
Hata: BLToolkit.Data.DataException: Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a Byte[]. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a Byte[]. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.SetCoercedValueInternal(Object value, MetaType metaType)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterBinding.PrepareForBind(OracleConnection connection, Int32& offset)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.ExecuteOperation[T](OperationType operationType, Func`1 operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.OnOperationException(OperationType op, DataException ex)
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.HandleOperationException(OperationType op, Exception ex)
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.ExecuteOperation[T](OperationType operationType, Func`1 operation)
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.ExecuteNonQueryInternal()
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at BLToolkit.Data.DbManager.BLToolkit.Data.Linq.IDataContext.ExecuteNonQuery(Object query)
   at BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Query`1.NonQueryQuery(IDataContextInfo dataContextInfo, Expression expr, Object[] parameters)
   at BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Query`1.<SetNonQueryQuery>b__e(QueryContext ctx, IDataContextInfo db, Expression expr, Object[] ps)
   at BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Query`1.Insert(IDataContextInfo dataContextInfo, T obj)
   at BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Extensions.Insert[T](IDataContext dataContext, T obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Guid (UniqueIdentifier) data type in Oracle, you must instead provide a byte array. In Oracle, define your Guid as a RAW(16), and then in your C# program, use the method Guid.ToByteArray().

Comment: I don't know BlToolkit, sorry... I use the Data Application Block in the Enterprise Library and NHibernate. Both of them override the behavior of the Guids with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

BLToolkit supports GUID for Oracle as RAW(16):

https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/b9dae9888047db5df4f5cbc6a705aabfc629712c/Data/Create%20Scripts/Oracle.sql#L504

and how to use it:

https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/5107745c15f6f04271f0a2140ab96c62054834fa/UnitTests/Linq/Types.cs#L126

Comment: Which part of code in question, I should edit to make it work?